# Perl subroutine documentation

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does Perl have something like Java/PHP Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133930/does-perl-have-something-like-java-php-docs)
>   [What's the best way to document Perl code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190755/whats-the-best-way-to-document-perl-code)

is there a way to write a subroutine docs?
such as

`sub add {

#docs: this subroutine adds two numbers 

}` 



and extract that info later?

Answer (score 6):

The standard method for writing Perl documentation is with [POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html). The `perldoc` command will extract POD and display it nicely for you. You can also use various tools like `pod2html` to turn it into HTML.

Answer (score 4):

There is a javadoc like setup called pod. You can learn more about it via: `perldoc perlpod` or here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html

Comment: It is worth noting that perldoc predates Java.